# Property only usable if parent class is specific

Tags: c#, properties

It's probably very simple but I'm a newbie on C#. Some classes :

```
public class Extension {
      Public string Name;
      Public List<View> Views;
}

public class Module : Extension {
     // ...
}

public class Component : Extension {
    // ...
}

public class View {
    // ...
}
```

And a collection :

```
List<Extensions> MyExtensions = new List<Extensions>() {
    new Component { 
        Name = "Component",
        Views = new List<View>() {

        }
    }
    new Module { 
        Name = "Module",
        Views = new List<View>() {

        }
    }
}
```

How to add a property FOO in View usable only is his parent is a Component ?

Comment: The parent class in both cases is `Extension`. Do you mean if the ***subclass*** is `Component`?

Comment: What do you by "only if his parent is a Component"? What parent? It's really unclear what you're asking at the moment.

Comment: `Extension` has a `List<View>`. I think OP wants `View` to expose a property `Foo`, only if it is in the List of `Component` and not `Module`. How that would make any sense, I can't even begin to understand.

Comment: Corak you have understand my request.

Comment: @user2705397 do you mean that you want a `View` that is owned by a `Component` to have different properties than a `View` which is owned by `Module`? If that is the case, please describe a scenario in which such properties are used.

Comment: Ok an example with my List<Extension> :
`new Component { Views = new List<View>() { FOO ="property exposed" },
new Module { Views = new List<Module>() { // No property exposed }`

Answer (score 1):

As your classes are setup right now, you're not going to be able to get that result without resorting to some super-hacky code. Instead, I think you should change your classes to this:

```
public abstract class View
{
    // ...
}

public class ModuleView : View
{ 

}

public class ComponentView : View
{
    public object Foo; //Substitute object with whatever type Foo is
}

public abstract class Extension
{
  public string Name;
  public abstract List<View> Views { get; set; }
}

public class Module : Extension 
{
    public override List<View> Views 
    {
        get
        {
            ModuleView moduleViewA = new ModuleView();
            ModuleView moduleViewB = new ModuleView();
            //Continue building whatever ModuleView objects you need...

            return new List<View>()
            {
                moduleViewA,
                moduleViewB,
                //...plus all other ModuleView objects you built
            };
        }
        set 
        {
            Views = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Component : Extension 
{
    public override List<View> Views
    {
        get
        {
            ComponentView compViewA = new ComponentView();
            ComponentView compViewB = new ComponentView();
            //Continue building whatever ComponentView objects you need...

            return new List<View>()
            {
                compViewA,
                compViewB,
                //...plus all other ComponentView objects you built
            };
        }
        set
        {
            Views = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This guarantees that only a `Component` object will ever be able to see field `Foo`.

Comment: This code will not compile because 1) you can't have abstract fields since they can't be overridden and 2) you can't change the type of the `Views` property when overriding it.

Comment: @D Stanley: you're correct that there's a compile error; I forgot to hit Build in VS. However, you CAN have `abstract` fields in C#, as long as you use the `override` keyword on their non-abstract descendents. I edited my code sample so that it builds properly now.

Answer (score 0):

The *purpose* of your request is very vague but one option you may have - if `Component` is defined in the same assembly as `View` - is to make the property [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  This makes the property visible only to types in the same assembly.

Of course, that means that `Module` (and any other types that you want to "hide" `Foo` from) will need to be defined in a different assembly, otherwise it would have access to the property as well.

`Assembly1.dll`:

```
public class Extension {
      Public string Name {get; set;}
      Public List<View> Views {get; set;}
}

public class Component : Extension {
    // View.Foo is accessible here;
}

public class View {
    internal object Foo {get; set;}
}
```

`Assembly2.dll`:

```
public class Module : Extension {
     // View.Foo is not visible here
}
```